# How do I remove this bright line on the left edge of my picture?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I wanted to create images from bin file. After the generation I noticed the white line on the left. The created image is ok but I think that white line is reducing the dynamic range of the picture and small values are less visible.

The code in python which lets me to create image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np
import json
import pickle
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import PIL.ImageOps
#from libtiff import TIFFfile, TIFFimage
import tifffile

def micronToStep(v):
    #approximately 62nm/step
    return round((v * 1000)/62)

def normalizeData(data):
    return (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))

def moving_average(x, w):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w

def annot_max(x,y, ax=None):
    xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
    ymax = y.max()
    text= "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=60")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="right", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(0.94,0.96), **kw)


fo = open('saveData2.bin', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(fo)
fo.close()


print("xyStep: ", data['xyStep'])
print("xRange: ", data['xRange'])
print("yRange: ", data['yRange'])
print("zRange: ", data['zRange'])
print("zBase: ", data['zBase'])

dimX = math.ceil(data['xRange'] / data['xyStep'])
dimY = math.ceil(data['yRange'] / data['xyStep'])
print(dimX, dimY)
img = np.zeros((dimX, dimY)).astype('uint16')

zRange = data['zRange']
imgData = data['data']
minValue = 999999999
maxValue = -999999999


for i in range(0, dimX):
    for j in range(0, dimY):
        if type(imgData[i][j]) is np.ndarray:

            try:
                smoothed = moving_average(imgData[i][j], 10)
                height = smoothed.argmax() # / smoothed.shape[0]) * zRange
            except TypeError:
                height = 0

            #if imgData[i][j] is None:
            #    height = 0
            #    print("none", i,j)
            #else:
            #    height = imgData[i][j].argmax()

            img[i][j] = height
            minValue = min(minValue, height)
            maxValue = max(maxValue, height)
            
           
print("Min: ", minValue)
print("Max: ", maxValue)


tifffile.imwrite('saveData2.tif', img)
```

The created image looks like this:

[image]

On the left there is a white line, it has the length of picture and width of one pixel.

The question is how to remove it during processing to increase the dynamic range of other part of the picture?

Comment: how to remove it? slice it off or overwrite those values in the array...

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on Christoph's comments, and assuming you have a single-channel (greyscale) image in Numpy array named `im`...

Cut off left-most column with:

```
im = im[:, 1:]
```

Zero left-most column with:

```
im[:, 0] = 0
```

---

Here's a little demo:

```
import numpy as np

# Create 3x3 mid-grey image
im = np.full((3,3), 128, np.uint8)

print(im)
```

Looks like:

```
array([[128, 128, 128],
       [128, 128, 128],
       [128, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8)

# Zero first column
im[:,0] = 0
print(im)
```

Looks like:

```
array([[  0, 128, 128],
       [  0, 128, 128],
       [  0, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8)

# Remove first column
im = im[:, 1:]
print(im)
```

Looks like:

```
array([[128, 128],
       [128, 128],
       [128, 128]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: no it will not.

Comment: I mean the corrected will be: `...try: imgData[0][j] = 0`?